# BeautifulSoup + Selenium, send dynamic table text built with divs to a list

Tags: python, list, selenium, dynamic, beautifulsoup

I am **scraping** generated table data with Selenium and sending to Beautiful Soup.
The script below will pull all text data (which I want). Unfortunately it seems to make just a one element list that joins all the text together.

How can I have beautiful soup filter on the div class "table-container" for text, and send each text item to a list as an item?

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options = options)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

url = "https://website.com/threats/blocked-connection?timeframe=day&timestamp=" +  str(int(time.time())) + "&visualization=table&tab=source&compareBy=bytes&logType=threat_history&threattype=blocked-connection&logcat=0"

driver.get(url)

username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("secretkey")
username.send_keys("myusername")
password.send_keys("mYpAsSw0rd!")

driver.find_element_by_name("login_button").click()

mylist = []

time.sleep(10)
html = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

mylist = [quote_tag.text for quote_tag in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'table-container'})]

print(mylist)
```

This is what the output looks like right now. One list, one huge item:

```
['www.web1.com (10.0.0.51)9c:8a:cb:53:d0:400 B661,980www.web2.com (10.10.10.101)11:22:33:aa:bb:cc0 B70521,15010.10.11.119c:8a:cb:53:d0:400 B16,429492,87010.10.11.119c:8a:cb:53:d0:400 B822,460']
```

However I want a list of separated items, list this:

```
['www.web1.com (10.0.0.51)','9c:8a:cb:53:d0:40','0 B','66','1,980', 'www.web2.com (10.10.10.101)','11:22:33:aa:bb:cc','0 B','705','21,150','10.10.11.11','9c:8a:cb:53:d0:40','0 B','16,429','492,870','10.10.11.11','9c:8a:cb:53:d0:40','0 B','82','2,460']
```

Here is a screen shot of what the structure looks like for the first item:
[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dive into deeper tags.

```
mylist = [quote_tag.text for quote_tag in soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'table-container'}).find_all('span')]

print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = []

for quote_tag in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'table-container'}):

   mylist.append(quote_tag.text)
```

Comment: This still creates just one giant list, same as shown above.

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted. c"However I want a list of separated items, list this". Your example was " one giant list":  [x,x,x,x,x,x,x,x]

Comment: Sorry if my description was confusing. The first example was what I was getting with my original code "This is what the output looks like right now. One list, one huge item:", I did not want that. The second comment states what I did want "However I want a list of separated items, list this:"